# Why class loader function doesnot executed while running jar using maven

Tags: java, maven, jar

Hi I am using maven3 to build my project. I am able to generate the jar file using maven clean,maven build,maven package comands. My aplication contains scheduler function which uses quartz scheduler. Executed the jar using java -jar jarname.jar, and it started the running but stoped at class loader function which was running perfectly in eclipse. and it doesnot show any exception. Instead of using maven in eclipse when jar is created by using export option it was running perfectly.

Here is the code where i use class loader function

```
public void classLoadder(String comNam, JmsTemplate jtScrap, JmsTemplate jtExpiry){
    String classFullName = "org.scrappers.Scrap."+ comNam ;         

    try{
        Class<?> cl = Class.forName( classFullName );
        Class<?>[] argTypes = new Class[] { JmsTemplate.class,JmsTemplate.class };
        Object obj = cl.newInstance();
        Method method = cl.getMethod("scrapAndIndex", argTypes);
        method.invoke(obj, (Object) jtScrap, (Object) jtExpiry);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you know it stops there if there is no error message?!

Comment: The maven error and/or the stacktrace would be useful addendum here I believe.

Answer (score 0):

check your eclipse config about maven.if you can run it out of eclipse then the error must be in your enviroment.